# Preventing php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:

Tags: php, fopen, getaddrinfo

I am trying to call an URL with PHP to check if it exists and is reachable.

My initial code was

```
fopen('http://'.$this -> url, 'r');
```

But it throws the following errors every time an URL is unreachable:

```
fopen(http://dwzegdzgwedzgew.com): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed
php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:
```

The error operator (@) is ignored in this case as the error isn't thrown by fopen itself but while resolving the asdress. So I thought that should do it:

```
 @fopen(@'http://'.$this -> url, 'r');
```

but it also goes on throwing the error.

Is there a non-error-throwing possibility to check if an URL exists within PHP before opening it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the error message with `$ressource = @fopen('http://' . $this->url, 'r');` ?

```
<?php


$urls = array('kihgkighuhgkig.li', 'google.com', 'adsfafdf.fr');
foreach ($urls as $url)
{
    if (gethostbyname($url) != $url)
    {
        $ressource = fopen('http://' . $url, 'r');
        var_dump($url, $ressource);
    }
}
```

The output is :

```
$> php test.php
string(10) "google.com"
resource(6) of type (stream)
```

Comment: fopen(http://kihgkighuhgkig.li): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Der angegebene Host ist unbekannt. 
Edit: Sorry for german, "unknwon host"

Comment: You can try to ping the request before using fopen. But if it's in production, hide errors `error_reporting(0);`

Comment: I am not able to hide errors for the whole project as the project has it's own errorhandling. Also to ping in PHP you need to create a socket, which would throw exactly the same error and have the issues stated above in the OP when trying to resolve the host.

Comment: I've edit my previous answer, for adding some code, did it works?